# Silverlight DataForm not triggering EditEndedEvent and not committed on AddNewItems

Tags: silverlight-4.0, event-handling, dataform, edmx

I have a Silverlight User Control. This contains a DataForm with  templates for ReadOnly, Edit, and New.

The template mode are working well and editing form are working perfectly. but when i use AddNewItem, I cannot do all the things except it never called EditEnded event, However it calls EditEnding and it lost without any warning  after that.

I used Datacontext.CommitEdit for commit while in New mode. Which then suppose to trigger EditEnded and do SubmitChanges if there are no errors and if DataContext has any changes. Since the logic is not going inside EditEnded I could not do anything.

It would be helpful, if I could get some suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error was because of exception in database due to "NOT NULL" property for TimeStamp row. I solved it by changing TimeStamp row to "NOT NULL" in models (entity models).